# how to ssh to root of my virtual machine unbuntu 14.04

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04

My host is mac and I create ubuntu 14.04 using VirtualBox.I am trying to ssh to its root account having set a password for root.
when I execute `ssh -vvv root@ip` and input my password.
Following is debug infomation:

```html
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

how can I connect my virual machine?

Answer (score 0):

The SSH daemon does not allow root logins by default.

You must just add this line to your `/etc/sshd_config` file:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Be careful! ssh to root does not log what's happening.
It is better to have a user with `sudo` permissions. This gets logged for later investigation.